# Css background image name from url variables

Tags: php

I have a landing page where I'd like to split test multiple backgrounds and popup overlays.

In the same folders I have images like 01.jpg 02.jpg etc.

The url will be similar to these:

mywebsite.com?bg=01&ov=01

mywebsite.com?bg=07&ov=10

etc...

I'd like to set a default value in case someone reaches the page with the clean url and also take care of security by allowing only numbers in the filename.

Here's what I have put together (it doesn't work):

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['bg']){
$bg = (int) abs($_GET['bg']);
}else{
$bg = '01';
}

if(isset($_GET['ov']){
$bg = (int) abs($_GET['ov']);
}else{
$ov = '01';
}

?>

<style>

body    {   
    background-image: url(<?php echo $bg; ?>.jpg);        
    background-size: cover;   
}

   .overlay {  
    background-image: url(<?php echo $ov; ?>.jpg);        
    background-size: cover;   
}
</style>
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: remove the `(int) abs()`. If you pass `01` that will definitely remove the leading zero

Comment: "it doesn't work"... Can you be more specific ?